# How to search in TableView by Section and Row?

Tags: swift

How to search in TableView by Section and Row ?

Get nested JSON from the site.

```
self.partnerBranchs = try decoder.decode([PartnerBranch].self, from: data)
```

Model:

```
struct PartnerBranch: Decodable {
let id: Int?
let address: String?
let contacts: String?
let name: String?
let logo: String?
let stocks: [Stock]
}

struct Stock: Decodable {
let id: Int?
let title: String?
let description: String?
let images: String?
}
```

**PartnerBranch** is a **section**
**Stock** is a **row**

How do I search for both?

Now works only on sections:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
partnerBranchsFiltered = partnerBranchs.filter({ (partnerBranch: PartnerBranch) -> Bool in
return partnerBranch.name!lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()
})
```

As I understand it I have to somehow use compactMat for stocks.

Comment: What do you want the filtered elements to be?

Comment: What is the criteria for searching? Are you aiming to search for `PartnerBranch` - `name` as well as `Stock` - `title`?

Comment: Yes, I want to filter the name of the partner and the title of the stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use reduce here. From how i understand your problem, it seems that you want to show the whole section if the search term matches your section title. But if it doesn't, you still want to show the section along with the matching rows. So, you could achieve it with reduce, like this,

```
let filteredBranchs: [PartnerBranch] = partnerBranchs.reduce(into: []) { (result, branch) in
    let partnerNameMatches = branch.name?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) ?? false
    if partnerNameMatches {
        result.append(branch)
    } else {
        let rowMatches = branch.stocks.filter({ (stock) -> Bool in
            return stock.title?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) ?? false
        })
        if !rowMatches.isEmpty {
            var filteredPartnerBranch = branch
            filteredPartnerBranch.stocks = rowMatches
            result.append(filteredPartnerBranch)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: line **filteredPartnerBranch.stocks = rowMatches** gives an error: Cannot assign to property: 'stocks' is a 'let' constant

Comment: @xew how come? `filteredPartnerBranch` is declared a var and works fine for me. Check your code.

Comment: Changed your text by adding **lowercased()** and changed **let stocks: [Stock]** on **var** in **PartnerBranch** model. And it worked! :D But just like in the previous example: **Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range** on **return partnerBranchsFiltered[section].stocks!.count**

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change: `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if isFiltering() {
            return partnerBranchsFiltered.count
        }
        
        return partnerBranchs.count
    }` Thanks a lot for your help!))))

Comment: @xew you should probably convert you search text also to lower case.